# @SASI.StandardAnalyzed | Tables cannot have more than 0 SASI indexes, failed to create SASI index on table user

Tags: spring-data-jpa, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra, datastax-astra

I am using the Cassandra database (via Datastax AstraDB) for a search query like

```
SELECT * FROM userdb.users WHERE skill LIKE %jav% AND skill LIKE %node% AND updatedate BETWEEN "1641839170" AND "1641839370" AND City LIKE "Chen";
```

I read about SASI Indexes which can help with queries like the above. But while I create SASI indexes using the Spring boot application, I get the below error.

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Tables cannot have more than 0 SASI indexes, failed to create SASI index on table user"
```

UserModel:

```
@Table
@Data
@Builder
public class User {
  @PrimaryKey private Long userId;
  private String username;

  @SASI(indexMode = CONTAINS)
  @SASI.StandardAnalyzed
  private String skill;

  @SASI(indexMode = CONTAINS)
  @SASI.StandardAnalyzed
  private String project;

  @SASI(indexMode = CONTAINS)
  @SASI.StandardAnalyzed
  private String city;

  @Column("updatedDate")
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TIMESTAMP)
  @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
  private LocalDateTime updatedDate;

  @Column("createdDate")
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TIMESTAMP)
  @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
  private LocalDateTime createdDate;

}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that SASI indexes are supported by DataStax Astra - it's the old & very buggy implementation of indexing. DataStax products support [Storage Attached Indexes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/docs/using-storage-attached-indexing-sai.html) that have less overhead compared to SASI, and should be more scalable. But I'm not sure that there is support for it directly in the Spring Data Cassandra.